# How to write a Dart Web build script?

Tags: dart

I really like Dart Web, but I don't like that when I run `webdev build` it always takes almost 10 seconds on a mysterious `Creating build script` step.

So, I thought: why not write my own build script to `webdev` doesn't need to build that!? The problem is that I can't find documentation on this anywhere.

I can see some documentation on https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_web_compilers but it doesn't explain much.

Is there a hidden guide somewhere on how this all works (what exactly is webdev and how it relates to build_web_compilers) and what I can do in a build sript?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/dart-lang/build